# Local convolution in Keras or Matconvnet

Tags: tensorflow, caffe, keras, keras-layer, matconvnet

I am new to implementing CNNs. I have some experience with Keras and Matconvnet. I am trying to implement region layer of the paper:[DRML network for AU detection](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_2016/papers/Zhao_Deep_Region_and_CVPR_2016_paper.pdf) which as follows :-
[image]

Here the input to 64 filters in Region layer is a different portion of the conv1 output as visible in following picture. (2, 2) and (7, 3) map to different filter.

As far as I know there is no such support in Keras and matconvnet as of now and if there is I would like to know how to implement it. Basically the filters should operate at a portion of it instead of whole input feature map.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Here(https://github.com/knsong/caffe-mt) is a local convolution layer and maybe it can help.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any such support for keras or matconvnet ?